# How to customize <h:messages/> style in JSF 2?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have an HTML message error already done by the front end developer, so I need to use strictly his design.

Do I need to write a component inherited of `<h:message/>` and implement the rendering? Or there is other easy way to display some html automatically inside it when I add error on JSF context using `FacesMessage` mechanism?

The perfect solution would be, when I add a `FacesMessage` in the context my `<div>` with custom HTML would be displayed. Is it possible?

How can I make this kind of customization? How is the easy way?

I don't want to ouse `OutputMessage` because I will not using the `FacesMessage` mechanism.

Comment: Which kind of customization? It is hard to tell from your question.

Comment: I just want to show some custom HTML when I add `FacesMessage` in the JSF context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML should be added in the XHTML page. Anyway, you can use `FacesContext.getMessages(String)` to check if there is some message for a component (and render the appropiate HTML based on that).

For example

```
 <h:outputText value="Here is the message!:" rendered="#{myBean.messageForComponentX}"/>
 <h:message for="componentX"/>
```

And in your bean

```
public isMessageForComponentX() {
  return (FacesContext.getMessages("componentX") != null) && (FacesContext.getMessage("componentX") > 0);
}
```

You can also check the `<rich:notify>` and `<p:growl>` components (from RichFaces and PrimeFaces), for custom management of messages.